# Обновление контента на странице

Tags: python-3.x, парсер

Хочу собрать результаты с сайта https://www.liveresult.ru
Страница обновляется каждую секунду, не могу разобраться куда шлет запрос при обновлении и как получает ответ.

Comment: *"не могу разобраться"* -- что конкретно вы пытались сделать (по шагам), и что не получилось? К примеру, пытались посмотреть в инструментах разработчика в браузере, что он посылает? Знакомы ли вы из чего HTTP сообщение состоит? В каком формате сервер информацию присылает (json, html)? Необходимо ли javascript выполнять, чтобы запрос серверу выполнить? Какую конкретно информацию вы хотите получить?

Comment: @jfs смотрел через инструмент разработчика в хроме, ставил флаг preserve log и просто глазами отсматривал результаты (возможно просто не увидел нужного мне), как по-другому незнаю, к сожалению. На похожем ресурсе я смотрел, было так: каждую секунду сервер отправлял get запрос на адрес, в ответ приходил json. В нем была информация о результатах спортивных событий.